# SVG viewBox zoom in center (Raphael)

Tags: svg, zooming, raphael, center, viewbox

I try to zoom with mousewheel on a Raphael paper using viewBox. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9zu4U/2/) is the JSFiddle code.

it works but now i want to zoom in the center and i have no idea where to start. I guess i should change the viewBox x and y coordinates.
I have tried this (in the function handle(delta)):

```
x = paper.width - viewBoxWidth;
y = paper.height - viewBoxHeight;
paper.setViewBox(x,y,viewBoxWidth,viewBoxHeight);
```

but didnt work. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Since your question has been answered on the mailing list I'll paste this here for future reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/raphaeljs/K-84cOe8ZP8

Answer (score 4):

For Zoom Out:

```
var tempViewBoxWidth = viewBoxWidth;
var tempViewBoxHeight = viewBoxHeight;

viewBoxWidth /= 1.10;
viewBoxHeight /=1.10;

viewBoxX -= (viewBoxWidth - tempViewBoxWidth) / 2;
viewBoxY -= (viewBoxHeight - tempViewBoxHeight) / 2; 

paper.setViewBox(viewBoxX, viewBoxY, viewBoxWidth, viewBoxHeight, false);
```

Comment: Why divide by `1.10`?